# Choose random element from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a array of two elements like so:

```
 @recommendation_sets = [@recommendations_model_1, @recommendations_model_2]
```

`@recommendations_model_1` and `@recommendations_model_2` are arrays of products, which I display in my rails view.

In my view, I have render a partial like so:

View:

```
<%= render 'recommendations', :model_data =>  @recommendation_sets.sample %>
<%= render 'recommendations', :model_data =>  @recommendation_sets.sample %>
```

Partial:

```
<% model_data.each do |model_info| %>
   <div id = "prod_box"> 
   <div class="item_desc"><strong><%= truncate(model_info.title, :length => 30) %></strong></div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

I am trying to randomize the way the recommendation sets are presented. My current set up does not work because calling `sample` on `@recommendations_sets` may result in the same `recommendations_model` being rendered. How can I render each of the elements in the `@recommendation_sets` array while randomizing how they are presented?

Comment: How about using `.shuffle`?

Comment: Duh, wasnt thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Question not clear. what is the relation between `@recommendation_sets` and `@recommendations_sets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `sample` with something like `model_data: @recommendation_sets.shuffle`